# get current URL and previous URL when user pushes button

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, url

Newby here.

Could someone show me an example of the code needed to do the following:

User pushes a button on my web site (there is no information for him to input, and no form, he just clicks on a button). I have found the following code on another post, but don't know if it is correct (I am also getting a syntax error on it):

```
<form action="php_file.php"><input type="submit" value="Click"></form>
```

The author of the above code said "Insert your PHP-Code into the file php_file.php and click the button, your file will be opened. Insert header("Location: html_file.html"); at the end of your php-file to get back to the page."

This click of the button needs to instigate the programming to grab the current URL and previous URL and insert them into the mysql database on my server. I have "PHP_SELF" and "HTTP_REFERER", but still need to get the results into mysql.

I would like to do this using only html, PHP and mysql, if possible.

Thanks to everyone for any help!

Comment: Is using jQuery okay with you?

Comment: In JavaScript, `window.location.href` is the current url and `document.referrer` is the previous url. See my answer here for example use of referrer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465940/how-do-i-make-a-secure-link-to-a-page-on-my-website/7466037#7466037

Comment: @Justin Satyr, thanks but I want to try to do it with html and PHP if possible.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

if your first file happen to be a PHP one, write this HTML form there.

```
<form action="php_file.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="previous" value="<?=urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Click">
</form>
```

and then in the php_file.php

```
<?
$current  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$previous = $_POST['previous'];
```

though both variables will contain only partial url, without host name, schema and, possible, port. it's usually enough but if you need these absent parts, you'll have to add them manually.

as for the writing info into database and particular PHP syntax rules you have to find yourself a tutorial, because this site is devoted to answering questions, not online education nor doing someone's job for free.

Comment: Hi Col. Shrapnel, thanks, but I am getting syntax errors with this and no output because of them.

Comment: I'm not trying to be smart.  I am asking what the syntax errors in the code you shared above might be, and if they can be fixed?

Comment: there are no syntax errors. but there are some PHP syntax to follow and to learn

Comment: I have a page full of PHP with no syntax errors, so I think I am doing fairly good at that by now for an admitted newby.  What am I missing?  What is different about yours?  Why does your form generate two syntax errors?

Comment: it's HTML form, so, it should be escaped from PHP first

Comment: It is with other html, before any php.

Comment: Funny that you went back and fixed your code.  I figured it out and went back to check, and then saw your edit.  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you can manage it with cookie session, first thing you'll need to do is start a session and then define the space where you'll store the URL information e.g: $_SESSION["url"]

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["url"]=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And whenever you want to go to that particular page, add the header:

```
header('location: ' .$_SESSION["url"]. '');
```

Answer (score -1):

Current:

```
$currentUrl = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
```

Previous:

```
 $previousUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Note that some users may have browser preferences set that keep `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` from being set, so it's possible that it would come back empty.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen those lines of code but I need to know how to get a button click by the user to get the PHP started to run them.